# Pagination not working on home page

Tags: loop, pagination, homepage

I've a page named "share" with a complex loop that's working perfectly. This page is located at `domain.com/share`. Now I need to use this page as the home page, so I went to "Settings -> Reading" and chose that page as static page.

The problem now is that the pagination no longer works. On the actual page it shows like `domain.com/share/page/2` but now it shows as `domain.com/page/2` and it just loads the same content from the first page over and over no matter what page you're in.

I didn't do any other changes, just chose that page as front page basically. What are the possible solutions here?

I'm using WP Pagenavi if that makes any difference.

This is my `page.php` template:

```
<?
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

if (is_page('join')) $post_types = array('articles');
if (is_page('learn')) $post_types = array('actions');
if (is_page('share')) $post_types = array('articles', 'actions');

$category = get_query_var('category');
$type = get_query_var('type');

$args = array(
  'post_type' => $post_types,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query' => array('relation' => 'AND')
);

$taxonomies = array();
foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
  foreach (get_object_taxonomies($post_type) as $tax) {
    if (array_search($tax, $taxonomies) === false) $taxonomies[] = $tax;
  }
}

foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {

  $all_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names'));
  $query_terms = array(ucfirst($category), ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $type)));
  $cur_terms = array_values(array_filter(array_intersect($all_terms, $query_terms)));

  if (! empty($cur_terms)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
      'terms' => empty($cur_terms) ? $all_terms : $cur_terms,
      'field' => 'slug'
    );
  }
}

if (is_page('join')) $args['posts_per_page'] = 36;

$query = new WP_Query($args);

get_header();
Theme::toolbar();
?>

<div class="center">
  <div id="content">
    <? if ($query->have_posts()): ?>
      <? while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post() ?>
        <? get_template_part('content') ?>
      <? endwhile ?>
    <? else: ?>
    <? endif ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?
wp_reset_query();
Theme::pagination($query);
get_footer();
?>
```

And this is the pagination code in `Theme`:

```
function pagination($query = null)
{
  global $wp_query;
  if (empty($query)) $query = $wp_query;
  $is_paged = $query->max_num_pages > 1;
  ?>

  <? if ($is_paged): ?>
    <div class="center"><div id="pagination"><? wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $query)) ?></div></div>
  <? endif ?>

  <?
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm being stupid, but is there a particular reason that you call wp_reset_query(); before calling pagination?

Comment: Does your theme have a `front-page.php` template? If so, that will override your `page.php` template.

Comment: @mrwweb: Nop, no `front-page.php`. The content shows up fine, just like in `share`. The pagination shows up but all the pages load the content from the first one. I have infinite scroll, so it gets stuck and loads the same content over and over infinitely.

Comment: Can you enable WP_DEBUG and perhaps a dump of your $query especially when you go to the next page?

Comment: @netfreak: I have WP_DEBUG enabled. I just checked the query closely again, and in `page/2` it says `paged=>1`?! But on `share/page/2` it says `paged=>2`... I don't get it.

Comment: `is_page('share')` is no longer true when it's the front page, not sure if that's contributing to the issue.

Comment: @Milo: I tried with `is_front_page()` and it didn't make a difference, problem persists...

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion in comments. @elclanrs please file [edit]s with additional information, not comments.

Answer (score 10):

I had faced the same problem. And finally, I solved the problem.
Getting the current Pagination Number

```
<?php  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  ?>
```

For getting the current pagination number on a static front page (Page template) you have to use the 'page' query variable.

```
<?php  $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;  ?>
```

So you should use the `get_query_var('page')` instead of `get_query_var('paged')`. 
You can use `is_front_page()` function in if condition for frontpage query. Just as like-

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()) {
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
}else {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
}
```

Credit goes [here](https://github.com/stafmans/stafmans.wiki.wordpress/wiki/0.1-Issue-resolved:-pagination-on-Static-Front-Page)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test this, but the [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) page says:

> Pagination Note: Use `get_query_var('page');` if you want your query to work in a Page template that you've set as your static front page.

So, perhaps you need this:

```
$page_number = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

[ ... ]

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_types,
    'page'      => $page_number,
    'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND' ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using these code for pagination. on **index.php** for loop;

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    // add title,excerpt or permalinks 
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php pagination(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
        <?php // no posts found message goes here ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

than add following lines to **functions.php**

```
function pagination() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset the query before you generate the pagination, look these lines of your code:

```
wp_reset_query();
Theme::pagination($query);
get_footer();
```

I've not looked further more because of this. Fix this and tell if it fix the problem.